# Advise new users to stay engaged with their question

Tags: discussion, comment, asking-questions, new-users

A number of times recently I've seen a new user drop a simple question (some bad, but some OK questions), and it's got some misunderstanding of what they're working on or a confusing explanation, either of the question itself or the work done. Now that question could be improved (maybe even self-answered) if the ***user would only stick around and read comments***.

So - is there a way to advise users that they should check back every five minutes or so for comments and other responses? Maybe in "How to ask a good question"? While giving such advice in a comment is still worthwhile, it's often not getting read fast enough to improve save-able questions.

If this advice already exists, it probably could benefit from a little more prominence.

*Added*: Perhaps as observed there is shyness or language issues holding some new users back - the issue of (apparent) non-engagement is the same though. Now I wonder whether we need to make sure that new users know that comment responses would still be viewed favorably as engagement. We shouldn't expect question-level standards of language or precision in comments, even though we may also urge them to clarify and expand the question itself as needed. One point here is that *established* users need to make sure they do not appear hostile to such comments (while still pressing for detail if needed).

As a side observation, if I am debating on whether to vote a question up or down, new user engagement will often weigh on the positive side.

Comment: Yes. Notice that sometimes, it's not that the user isn't there paying attention to the comments, it's just that, it might take a considerable amount of time to grasp them.  You might also suggest them, in comments, to click on _Follow_ the answer, so that they don't miss subsequent comments or edits.

Comment: I sometimes suspect that if someone asks a question and immediately goes away, the question is probably homework. They think that when they come back in the morning it will all be answered.

Comment: "they should check back every five minutes or so...." What an absurd suggestion!

Comment: @GerryMyerson I’ll clarify that I mean immediately subsequent to posting - so check back say four times in the half-hour after posting. Would you still consider that absurd?

Comment: @Verónica yes I was considering whether a possible help might be to have notifications **on** by default , for the first two or three questions asked. They could still be turned off of course, but that would imply a level of commitment to understanding the site which is not always apparent.

Comment: It's my understanding that users do get notified of comments on their questions, Joffan, so I'm not sure what you mean by "having notifications on by default".

Comment: You always get the message icon active - if you're on the site. There's some other pushier notification available too I think - e-mails? Anyway I was really responding to Vero's comment on *Follow* notification.

Comment: From what I have observed, new users with borderline questions from a site policy standpoint (brief attempt, some terms not defined, and no latex), will often receive a comment asking for clarification, several downvotes, and eventually question closure. While I imagine I would want to improve my question after one or two of these events, I would simply through up my hands after all of them (if I was a new user). My suggestion to keep new users engaged is simply to send less negative feedback at once.

Comment: Well, when I ask any question, I am a bit restless and do check every 5 or 10 mins for any update (it's very convenient on mobile device). In fact I am not able to focus on other things on that day. That explains why I have asked only a few questions so far.

Comment: @user400188: delaying closure of poor questions has another undesirable effect : answers by FGITW and that usually leaves no further hope of any interaction with asker.

Comment: I still think that if users are given some quick and positive response within 10 mins of posting the question then they would respond. And any update of the question (including fixing mathjax) by the asker in that time is almost sure sign that the asker is serious and willing to engage. Such cases are however rare and not the norm.

Comment: I confess I'm a member of the "fire-and-forget" brigade myself. After dumping a question on MSE I go away, log into another website, and get on with something else entirely. It may be over an hour later when finally I get back to my question to see if somebody has answered it. Sometimes they have, sometimes they haven't. Goes 2 ways. Several answers I've posted to questions which have had zero acknowledgement for. I don't think it's anything you can police. Can't be bothered with fake politeness, me. If you don't like me, then don't answer my stupid question, stupid, is how I think.

Comment: @PrimeMover - that's OK if you know how to ask a question; you don't need to hang around to learn more about expectations of the site and clear up what it actually is that you're asking. I'm only talking about the first two or three questions of a new user.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh "quick and positive response within 10 mins of posting the question" is fine if they read it; the point here is that any unread response, no matter how positive, has no effect. And I'll assume that by *positive* here you mean *polite and encouraging* rather than pretending that any problems of clarity or context don't exist.

Comment: @Joffan: yes your assumption is correct. Comments regarding lack of context or mathjax may be given after polite and encouraging comments which motivate towards a solution to the problem at hand. I am trying to adhere to this protocol for questions related to my expertise.

Comment: The idea is to convince the new user that we are here to help you out. Like we can ask as a first comment "did you try integrating by parts, it is not so difficult" and then "once you have tried integration by parts let us know any issues and you can use mathjax tutorial to post your attempt".

Comment: @ParamanandSingh To check we're on the same wavelength here - the issues of clarity and context should be raised in that first comment (politely and with some encouragement), not as an afterthought. We may differ a little on MathJax - I regard using full MathJax format as secondary and *once it is a question worth keeping* I would hope commenters would take a few moments to help update the question, as well as point out the resources available..

Comment: @ParamanandSingh There's a line to tread here, certainly - however tagging on a remark like "it's not so difficult" is not encouraging to someone who finds it difficult.

Comment: Ok some questions are so poor (as per my judgement) that I have to use something like "questions which are just problem statements are discouraged here, voting to close". But for not so poor questions we need to encourage them as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: Yep, I don't advocate trying to interpret or support word salad.

Comment: That "difficult" line was an example. We need to give some sort of hope based on the question.

Comment: @Joffan How about "If you take such-and-such an approach, you find it is fairly straightforward", or "... you will find it works out to a simple expression" and so on. I too find things like "It's really not so difficult" sound condescending.

Comment: @PrimeMover Do agree, however, with the condescending nature of the comment "it is not so difficult", I would prefer something like "you are two steps away from the answer", along with the alternatives you suggest. What I felt is that being positive and indicative of progress with a user, is the right way ahead if the user's question is close-worthy but improvable. The split in opinion is that others put hints /complete answers up because they think the question is good enough , or (which we should try to cut down) just like to answer any question which comes in for reputation or whatever.

Comment: (Let us recall comments are not meant to be used for extended discussion, and to keep a civil tone at all times.)

Comment: The idea of improving the post incentivized by promising progress on the problem is the best way, I think, of having users check back, because the only thing we can control is our impression of them, and staying within the site's etiquettes that impression is : "help us, and we promise to help you". If that message goes through, I can imagine a user being receptive to feedback. Once again, however, no user is going to check back if they know that their question will be answered whatever happens, so we have to cut down on users that answer PSQs for this relationship to blossom.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon When I first started answering q's on this forum I used to go with "here is a hint as to how to start, now proceed from here" but I was soundly scolded in the comments and voted down for not having provided a full answer. My personal view is that this is unhelpful because it does not offer the questioner the opportunity of learning by doing. However, it is appreciated that this is a q-and-a repository rather than a site set up specifically to teach students.

Comment: This question really hits home for me. Part of the reason I've been reluctant to engage frequently with commentators is that on many websites this is considered poor form and excessively argumentative. But now I know the culture here is different, I'll try to get over this reluctance.

Answer (score 14):

This may be a controversial answer, but I think the low investment of users in non homework cases maybe due to the following:

1. The mathematical maturity of the user is not enough to understand the content of the comment and they are shy to ask clarification.
2. The user is either preparing for an exam/ a course, so they can't spend more than some reasonable time on one particular point which is confusing.
3. The answerer/commenter doesn't seem to understand what the OP is asking/ the phrasing of OP and doesn't ask for clarifications on that.

These are reasons I myself have given up on some questions I have asked. To make the previous statement less bad, I try my best to attend and read through each answer I get even if it's months after and write answers to old questions if I ever end up figuring them out because I think that it may help someone else who has the same / similar query out.

As an answerer, the only one you can control is the 3rd point, there is a certain skill to be able to understand what others are saying. I won't say I am the best person to advice others on this, but I can definitely say that this is a thing for a person who wants more of their answers to be accepted to think about.

And as a final point, if the question is well phrased, then it doesn't matter even if OP abandons because the question is for helping a large group of people rather than giving special help to OP.

Even answers to exercises and problems can be helpful (even if OP doesn't attend to it) , I have found many example questions/ edge case questions which have helped me in my studies by browsing MSE.

P.S: These are just my views

Comment: I don't have much to argue about there; my quandary here specifically is how to emphasize to new users the value of actually engaging with the community, at least **immediately after they pose a question**. That would allow some of the issues described (#1 & #2) to actually be uncovered. The behaviour of people answering, #3, seems like a separate topic. And well-posed questions are also not an issue here, the point is vague and ambiguous questions that don't meet standards. If the asker is reading & responding to comments, this issue does not arise (even if other issues do).

Comment: What you are saying is the 'effect', I am trying to address the cause. I think if the cause is correctly addressed then it at least becomes clear to what issue we are trying to fix.

Comment: I don't think in the case I'm discussing we even get as far as what you're calling here "cause". You're addressing a different (and perhaps valid) problem of driving people away; I'm addressing a problem of people not engaging sufficiently in the first place.

Comment: Right, so if people aren't engaging, then that means there are barriers which keep them from engaging. The correct course, would be to identify the reasons why they wouldn't be engaging, it would be good if you could add the reasons you think they aren't as an answer/ edit to your question @Joffan

Comment: Another point is language barrier.